# Generic type 'Component<P, S>' requires 2 type argument(s)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm trying to use `ts` and `react-router` v4 to make a demo, and I will get the error.

```
Failed to compile.

Error in D:\data\code\taven\react-components-usage-ts\node_modules\@types\react-router\lib\withRouter.d.ts

(3,99): error TS2314: Generic type 'PureComponent<P, S>' requires 2 type argument(s).
```

Comment: Have you open an issue to `react-router` repo?

Answer (score 2):

I also saw this error. This error was made in the latest version for 2 weeks ago in version 4.0.12. Use the previous version. In it everything works OK.

npm install --save @types/react-router@4.0.11

The same thing happened with react-route-dom. Use:

npm install --save @types/react-router-dom@4.0.4

Comment: I don't want to use new router, It's hard to update it to new version. So how to be in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the interfaces for the props and state above the component.

```
interface P {
    sampleProp: string,
    awesomeProp2: number

}
interface S {}

PureComponent<P, S>
```

Comment: when i build the project, the error will come from the `react-router` lib

Comment: have you tried changing `PureComponent<P, S>` to `PureComponent<any, any>` It could be helpful to limit the error to a react-router definition.

Comment: `PureComponent` come from `react-router`, and I imported `react-router`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using React-Redux? This was updated a few days ago. I had to revert back to an older version.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blame/master/types/react-redux/index.d.ts#L179

This version worked for me.
"@types/react-redux": "4.4.32"

Comment: it was `@types/react` was build typescript 2.1, it was fixed use typescript 2.3. i don't know why